# Ubuntu - change block device location from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, blocking, device-manager, udev

Host: Ubuntu 15.04

I have a M.2 SSD and one hard-disk.

The hard-disk device location is normally at /dev/sda and the SSD is at /dev/sdb.

I looked into some posts and found out some possible approaches I may take.

1. Writing my own udev rule

   To do this, I need to modify the udev file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/xxx-persistent.rules` However, I only have 70-persistent-net.rules in my host and only net related devices appeared.

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="81:fb:5c:18:aa:d6", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
   ```

   Should I edit this file to add the rule here?
2. Edit the symlink in `/etc/disk/by-id ( or by-uuid )`
3. Edit the fstab file under /etc/fstab

   ```
     UUID=01d0c5a3-191b-4d59-91cd-99211226d5c9 /media/SSD/ ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
   ```

change to

```
  UUID=00d0c5a3-191b-4d59-91cd-99211226d5c9 /dev/sdc ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

although i added this line to the fstab ( the uuid is my ssd ), it still appears the device node is /dev/sda

This automatically mounts to `/dev/sdb`,  how can I change the path here?

I don't find the sample for the 2 point. 
Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious. Why do you want to swap these around? What goal are you trying to reach?

Comment: @Hennes For example, I may need to install the operating system through Internet to the specific device location, this swap will be needed.

Comment: Why not install it to /dev/sdb if you want it on /dev/sdb andif you want in on /dev/sda install it to /dev/sda? No dik mapping swap needed. The only reason I came up with is if you want to move one of the disk to a new system where it will have a different name by default. If you are going to do that a lot (e.g. the SSD in an external eSATA case and moving it around between several computers) then yes. Such a rule makes sense. But if you keep it in one desktop/laptop then just tell the bootloader or the installer to look at the other disk.

Comment: @Hennes I use PXE to install the operating system and the default PXE will install the OS to the specific device location ( /dev/sda ) for example. However, /dev/sda/ is not the device which I expect to install this OS. Hence, I need to swap it. I know to do this through the PXE script but I am wondering If I can do it by swapping the device node.

Comment: (continued). If you do write a rule, take a look at https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH71007. (note: no linux here to test with atm, and I am not 100% sure how M2 and SATA map to SCSI/SAS).

Comment: @Hennes I thought I can do it in /etc/fstab, can't I ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34524/discussion-between-user3815726-and-hennes).